# Problems with spaces in German Wikipedia API

Tags: api, wikipedia, spaces

I have a problem with spaces in querys for the German Wikipedia API. In the English version everything works fine, and the query is correctly normalized and redirected. I've tried "karl marx" as an example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=karl_marx&redirects=1&utf8=1&exintro=1&explaintext=1

However, the German version doesn't redirect although the normalization gives the same result:

https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=karl_marx&redirects=1&utf8=1&exintro=1&explaintext=1

Does someone have an idea of what to do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirects are set up manually. English Wikipedia has a `karl marx` -> `Karl Marx` redirect and German doesn't. This has got nothing to with spaces.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for explaining.